# I want to add my current url to to a meta tag for the attribute content

Tags: javascript, html, aem, window.location

I want to add my current url inside a meta tag for content value, currently its incorrect using some objects that are pointing at the wrong url.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="${request.requestURL.toString}" />
```

This returns the wrong url, this tag is inside a  component that is used in many other pages through out the site, so its recycled and i cant just hardcode the url.

This is what i tried to do with some javascript but it is not working and i believe it runs the script before it knows what url it is in .

```
<script>

    var currentLocation = window.location;
    </script>
<meta property="og:url" content="${currentLocation}" />
```

but it does not return the current location 
it just shows this when i do view page source
it does not even show the content attribute

```
<meta property="og:url"/>
```

[image]

If i inspected i can see the url being reference in the variable

Comment: What do you mean when you say "objects that are pointing at the wrong url"? Can you give some examples of what was the URL you were expecting and what did it return? You are probably using HTL in AEM which has some implicit objects. Provided the additional info, people might be able to suggest the right object and method for retrieving the details you need.

Answer (score 0):

html does not process javascript...it is a static language. You need to set it with the script

```html
<meta id="meta-location" property="og:url" content="" />

<script>
  document.querySelector('#meta-location').setAttribute('content', location.href)
</script>
```

Comment: hello i tried it and got an empty content `<meta id="meta-location" property="og:url" content=""/>`

Comment: Is the script tag after the meta tag? Any errors in browser console? How are you checking this?

Comment: yes the script tag is after the meta tag just like you put in your answer. location.href
"https://csstw.farmers.com/"

Comment: i check by checking the view page source , and thats the outcome

Comment: javascript doesn't affect the source...that is what is sent from server only

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: If you want it in the source that can only be done server side.

Comment: via my backend java ?

Comment: Whatever language you are using...yes

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run your script after your meta tags are loaded since JS edits the DOM after its initialized. Get the meta by property selector like so:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="" />

<script>
  document.querySelector('meta[property]="og:url"').setAttribute('content', location.href)
</script>
```

or you can use the name:

```
<meta name="url" property="og:url" content="" />

<script>
  document.querySelector('meta[name]="url"').setAttribute('content', location.href)
</script>
```

Comment: will this show up on the view page source ? its showing up with an empty content

Comment: @DavidArriaga small mistake in the syntax, try it again

Comment: wrong syntax, should be this: `document.querySelector('meta[property="og:url"]').setAttribute('content', location.href)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, with this you will achieve the full url in your meta tag.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="${request.scheme}://${request.serverName}:${request.serverPort}${currentpage.path}.html" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Java Classes for business logic (whether sling model or extending WCMPojo class)

I had similar functionality with canonical tags. What I did is returned a string (Url) from My `Model` and updating it acc to the given condition.

```
String url;
// getter of url


@PostConstruct
public void afterCreated() {

    url = url + domainName + slingRequest.getRequestURI();
 or
    url = slingRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
 or
    url = "Any modification you like";
}
```

in HTML

```
<sly data-sly-use.tagModel="Full class name" >
    <meta property="og:url" content="${tagModel.url}"/>
</sly>
```

This way you can debug easily and modify it accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the meta tag using **.querySelector()**
2. Set **window.location.href** (Your current URL) as the **content** of the
   meta tag using **.setAttribute()**

```js
<meta name="url" property="og:url" content="www.sample.com" />
<script>
    document.querySelector("meta[name=\"url\"]").setAttribute("content", window.location.href);
</script>
```